# Resources and control position in win32 programming

Tags: c, resources, winapi

I'm new in win32 programming and I've some questions about resources.

Must I use a resource editor (from Visual Studio) to make controls? I know it can be post-edited using a Resource Hacker editor. How to prevent it?

GUI created in Windows Forms (.net) or Borland Delphi (VCL) can't be edited using res hacker, maybe it creates controls at runtime.

Is a pointless work make all controls by runtime to prevent it to be edited by res hacker?

```
HWND hButton = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    _T("BUTTON"),
    _T("Click!"),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_LEFTTEXT,
    5, 5, 80, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL
);
```

Second question: isn't there a easy way to set position of a control in **top right** of parent window?

Today I'm doing it in this way:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    {
        HWND hButton;
        RECT rcParent, rcButton;

        hButton = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_BUTTON1);

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcParent);
        GetClientRect(hButton, &rcButton);

        if(!SetWindowPos(hButton, 0, rcParent.right - (rcButton.right - rcButton.left + 5), 5, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE))
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, _T("Error at WM_SIZE"), _T("Error!"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Are there something like Anchors in pure win32 programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource file format for dialogs is ancient. The only thing in its favor is the dialog unit abstraction that means that dialogs automatically scale to take account of the users preferred font face and display dpi settings.

Other than that, there is no support in the dialog format for anchors. Microsoft have sadly not released a new UI building toolkit however for native development so for Native Win32 apps you are stuck creating / positioning your controls at runtime manually for any task that dialog resources cannot cater for.

WPF is clearly superior, but requires .NET

I don't see the point of disallowing res hacking one way or another. What do you gain by preventing it? If your own layout skills are so bad that people will want to re-layout their dialogs "illegally" then... well wtf is all I can say.

To Summarize:

- It IS pointless to try and protect dialog layouts. What can you possibly hope to achieve by limiting something people would only resort to if your own layouts were #@%^ anyway.
- You WILL however probably want to create the controls at runtime anyway as the dialog resource format lacks modern features like anchors. Allthough it is a good idea to continue the practice of designing forms in units based on font metrics rather than pixels.
- If you want a pre-build "form" layout system with anchors, Win32 cannot help you. The QT framework if you want a cross platform c++ solution, or switching to .NET's WPF are both powerful alternatives that may allow you to leverage your existing non UI code.

Comment: That's a high performance and simple app, then I can't use .net here. But that's ok, I think I can create elements using resource editor then simulate anchors on WM_SIZE, setting the new position for each content. Finally, we've Ribbon which appears to be a nice UI running on C++.

Comment: Ribbon supplies a nice toolbar interface. In terms of the actual layout of the body of a window, you are still on your own.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a pointless work make all controls
>   by runtime to prevent it to be edited
>   by res hacker?

It's not pointless, it's only extra work. You will need also to code a resource editor and/or a layout manager to ease your work. You can define and handle your own resource definition file, and put it as a custom resource.

> Are there something like Anchors in
>   pure win32 programming?

No layout manager in pure win32. But you may find some free source code to do this. It's rather easy to do some minimal layout manager.

Answer (score -1):

Hi probably no becouse win32 api is base for most all graphics libs in windows. What can i recommend you its use some  graphics libs if you can do it in your project.